# Outbound IPv6 Trafic Fails

Tags: configuration, routing, ipv6, address

My hosting provider has supplied me with global static IPv6 for my machine. It appears that auto configuration has been successful and I can successfully ping my machine and tracepath6 appears to function correctly. I am running a 64bit Arch Linux distro.

However I am unable to ping any ipv6 device *from* the machine and all traceroutes fail at the auto configured link local router address.

How would you further troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seeen this when the device has the wrong subnet length specified (`/64` when it should be `/48`) etc.

Comment: Spot on! After changing my static configurations to utilized a 48 bit mask communication has resumed. Strange in that my provider provisioned the addressing details.

Comment: @benji - had the same issue with an ipv6 provider myself yesterday. They gave me a prefix length of /64 in the documentation, but it was actually a /48. These things are bound to happen during teething for early adopters.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick thing to check ... your running ping6 right (instead of ping).

Has your computer received a Global IPv6 address in addition to the local address?  Double check that.

Otherwise, check to make sure your machine has received a default route.  It's 'ip route -6' I think.  I have one router that sends screwed up router advertisements so Linux will properly add the address to the interface but not set it as a default route.  Can you ping6 your default route?

Otherwise, what machine are you pinging?  What is the exact error?

Comment: My interface is configured both with a local and global IPv6 address. Like I mentioned my machine responds to pings from external devices, however cannot ping external devices.

I am pinging ipv6.google.com. I get a host not reachable from my link local configured gateway.

From fe80::2d0:4ff:fefd:5c00 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address